# Issues building sbt tool while installing Spark

Tags: apache-spark

While installing Spark standalone mode on Ubuntu, I am facing issue while running sbt/sbt assembly command, it says No such file or directory found. I did installation from scratch which Covers installation of Java, Scala, Git and finally building Spark using sbt tool. I followed the below tutorial for installations.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQ0nPdfVfc0

Comment: https://www.santoshsrinivas.com/installing-apache-spark-on-ubuntu-16-04/